# asp.net uninstall and remove all membership tables and stored procedures from production webserver

Tags: asp.net, webserver

A serious problem occured with my database. I have today installed membership tables in my webserver using aspnet_regsql.exe by giving authentication details. Later I realised it was of no use. So i decided to remove them all. Searching everywhere I found running command line aspnet_regsql and supplying suitable attribute to remove.

But How can i run command line tool on webserver. I need to uninstall all tables created by aspnet_regsql only since my database has other tables too. And I dont want to loose records already registered.

I need to remove tables stored procedures views and all things created by that tool.

**Suggestions?**

Please help me to uninstall it using Visual Studio or any built in tool. Because I dont have SQL Server 20o8 R2 and management studio of R2 which is on my webserver

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just sort the tables by date created using the object explorer view in SQL Server Management Studio and remove them that way.  You may also need to remove some stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Call it with -R, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says?

Comment: -r on a webserver ? How can I do that ? Is there any method to run command line command on webserver from remote site

Comment: Remote desktop to it. Otherwise run the operation on a backup of the database on another machine and restore that database to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the graphical interface by double clicking aspnet_regsql.exe, which is in

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

or

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

depending on which framework version you used for your application. Clicking next, select *'Remove application services information from an existing database'*. Then supply your db server IP and db credential (which can be found from your connectionString).

But before running this program, you have to make sure you deleted all records of aspnet_Membership and aspnet_Applications table. To delete an user, you can use membership procedure [dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser]. A sample call of this procedure is:

```
DECLARE @out int
EXEC [dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser] '/', 'username', 15, @out OUTPUT
```

You can use a db cursor to loop through all the users.